# How far is the point where the rear ends of the two trains cross each other given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Train T of length 100m moving at 54Kmph and Train U of length 150m moving at 90Kmph running on parallel tracks enter a 200m long tunnel at the same instant from opposite directions.
>
> $1$ ) How far is the point where the rear ends of the two trains cross each other, from the point of entry of the slower train?

options:

a) $40.5$m b)$81$ c)$84.5$ d)$68.75$

MyApproach:

I calculated that T is a slower train as it takes 20s with respect to U taking 14 sec.

I assumed that Let the point they meet where the 2 trains cross each other be x from the point of slower train.

Therefore,

Time elapsed before the ends meet for the $2$ trains=

> But,I am not able to think relatively

Am I doing right till here.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set the position of the entrance to the tunnel to $x=0$. Then see that the starting position of the rear of each train is just negative the length of train. Now, the slower train is moving at $54\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}$ and the starting position is $x_0=-0.1\:\text{km}$, so the position of the rear at a given time is
$$x_{slow}(t)=x_0+v\cdot t=-0.1+54\cdot t$$
Likewise for faster train:
$$x_{fast}(t)=-0.15+90\cdot t$$
All that's left is to solve for the position $x$ when
$$x_{fast}(t)=x_{slow}(t)$$

Comment: How do you reach to the formula?

Comment: Speed is position over time, or $v=\frac{x}{t}$. One can then solve algebraically to get $x=v\cdot t$, and then just move the zero point to the starting position, $x_0$.